# Restsharp portable parallel requests are sent successively by one instance of RestClient

Tags: c#, xamarin, parallel-processing, restsharp, rest-client

I use [restsharp.portable 3.1.3](https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/restsharp.portable) in my Xamarin native application. Usually all my requests are sent by one RestClient instance. That's because the creating and disposing of HttpClient are heavy operations for mobile application.
Sometimes I have some cases when my application should send several requests in parallel.

For example:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var maxTaskCount = 3;

        var client = new RestClient("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/");

        var tasks = new List<Task<IRestResponse>>();
        for (var i = 0; i < maxTaskCount; i++)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("photos");
            request.Method = Method.GET;

            var task = client.Execute(request);
            tasks.Add(task);
        }


        var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
```

While I was profiling my app using proxy(Fiddler or Charles) I found out some bottleneck inside restsharp.portable library. The requests are sent one by one successively. The rest sharp package has **AsyncLock** class with **LockAsync** method for synchronization all requests which are sent by one instance of RestClient.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Execute the given request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">Request to execute</param>
    /// <returns>Response returned</returns>
    public override async Task<IRestResponse> Execute(IRestRequest request)
    {
        using (await _requestGuard.LockAsync(CancellationToken.None))
        {
            using (var response = await ExecuteRequest(request, CancellationToken.None))
            {
                return await RestResponse.CreateResponse(this, request, response);
            }
        }
    }
```

That's why  I have had the performance issue which was solved by creating own RestClient instance for every requests which should be sent in parallel.

I have no idea why the [author](https://github.com/fubar-coder) of RestSharp portable decided to use AsyncLock inside his package. Maybe because the RestClient keeps some state inside it.

Bellow are the results of my research:

1. One RestClient instance and three API calls. As we can see all 3 calls are successive.
   [image]
2. Three RestClient instances and three API calls(one call for one RestClient instance). As we can see all three calls are parallel.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient didn't support parallel requests, which is the only reason AsyncLock exists. Maybe they've changed its implementation, but I haven't tested it yet.

EDIT: A possible solution around this limitation would be to use pooling for `IRestClient` instances.

Comment: Just FYI:
[RestSharp](https://components.xamarin.com/view/restsharp/) supports parallel requests because it bases on HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse.

Comment: @ZEvS can you provide more info? the link you send doesn't seem relating to the question.